# Php Page is all white

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

I am working on the PHP of a site and every time I put any PHP into the code, the whole page is white and refuses to compile.

Now I did the most basic thing I could imagine,on this page: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/PDO.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I am thinking that it has to be a server side problem, (never ran php on this domain before) but my host just told me that I must have a code error.

So my question, is there any way to see whats going on? (phpinfo is not an option sadly)

Comment: [`error_reporting(E_ALL)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)?

Comment: Check the Apache error log. What does it report?

Comment: If you cannot access any log files, try to add `ini_set('display_errors', true);` right after the first PHP opening tag to (hopefully) get an output.

Comment: Eighter you don't have PHP or you have a `htaccess` that blocks everything, check `http://www.trulyscience.com/test/`

Comment: Made it `<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true); 
error_reporting();
phpinfo();
?>` Still nothing

Comment: If you do this: `<?php phpinfo(); ?> Hello world!`, does `Hello world!` show up?

Comment: Yup: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/PDO.php
Does this mean that my PHP is turned off/broken?

Comment: It does appear to be broken somehow, your server is reporting that PDO.php is powered by PHP 5.2.17.

Comment: It's included in the HTTP response headers. (X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17)  So phpinfo(); doesn't work.  Does `echo "Hi there";` output anything?

Comment: A re-install of PHP may be in order.

Comment: It does echo when I do `<? echo'hi'; ?>`, and I can't reinstall, the server is maintained by the host (And they are stubborn and keep telling me that everything is fine and that I make PHP errors..) So it would be cool if I could know what was broken so I could tell them or prove it somehow.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder they've disabled `phpinfo` and the error reporting that would tell you that it is.  Though in your comment above it should have been <?php ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL); phpinfo(); ?>  The E_ALL is needed to set the error_reporting.

Comment: Oh wow, got a response :O `Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/parascie/public_html/Trulyscience.com/test/PDO.php on line 1`

Comment: That's why <?php phpinfo(); ?> was giving you a blank page, they've disabled it and the error reporting.  Their PHP is working fine it seems.  They just have a very paranoid setup.

Comment: I got the same prob with a page with actual code on it, so I ask em for turning on errors and phpinfo()? (Anything else I should ask to get turned on?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's not buried in a comment for when people stumble upon this question:

That's why  was giving you a blank page, the host has disabled it and the error reporting. Their PHP is working fine it seems. They just have a very paranoid setup.

PHP has the ability to not only turn off error reporting, but also the ability to suppress specific functions from operating.  A good absolutely minimal code to test with `<?php echo 'Hi'; ?>`

You can use `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`.  Of course, with this, some pages with compilation errors might give you a blank page.  You can ask your host to turn on error reporting or have them point you to a page explaining how you can turn it on, say via `.htaccess` since you're on Apache.  If you really need `phpinfo` you can ask the same of that.

Comment: I'll ask them to turn on errors, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, I write PHP and manage multiple servers for a living.  And for the benefit of anyone who lands here from a google search in the future, there's more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php